# Execute method after gridview update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I have a `GridView` that makes use of an `ObjectDataSource` that references a class that updates, creates, deletes and views info, each in its own method that calls a stored procedure to do the desired operation. I also have a hidden control on the page that holds a set of Id's that i send to the `SELECT` method in the class that is used in the stored procedure to load the data.

I set the value of this hidden control in the `Page_Load` event. This means that if I update a field in the `GridView` (i.e. changing one of the ID's) the control still has the old set of ID's. I need to run the method in my code-behind after the `GridView` is updated in order to load the correct new results.

I've been debugging and noticed that the `SELECT` method in the class connected to the ObjectDataSource is called just after the `UPDATE` method in the same class. How can I call a method in the code-behind just before this `SELECT`?

Comment: Can't you just create a method which runs on the GridView-Updated event?

Comment: @bodycountPP: this is actually perfect. For some reason I was using the GridView-Updating event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding to the [DataGridView.SelectedIndexChanging event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)([list of all events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). MSDN states:

> Occurs when a row's Select button is clicked,  but before the GridView
>   control handles the select operation.

Another helpfull event could be probably the `DataBinding` event.